# Logging to ElasticSearch using Serilog

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch, serilog

Is there a helpfull soul out there, who can help me get Serilog and its ElasticSearch module working in PowerShell?

I've found a guy that did get the [rolling file log](https://gist.github.com/rsgoheen/ba5fb610396b09e4481e) working, but I've been unable to find anything ElasticSearch examples.

```bsh
Add-Type -Path "Serilog.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "Serilog.Sinks.Seq.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "Serilog.Sinks.EventLog.dll"
Add-Type -Path "serilog.sinks.elasticsearch.dll"
Add-Type -Path "Serilog.FullNetFx.dll"
Add-Type -Path "Elasticsearch.Net.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "Serilog.Extras.AppSettings.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "Serilog.Extras.Timing.dll"

$config = New-Object -TypeName "Serilog.LoggerConfiguration"
[Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSinkConfiguration]$ConfigSink = $config.WriteTo

<#
[Serilog.Log]::Logger = [Serilog.LoggerConfigurationFullNetFxExtensions]::RollingFile
                                ($ConfigSink,
                                "C:\Logs\Log-{Date}.txt",
                        ([Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel]::Verbose), "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}", $null, 10000000, 15).CreateLogger()
#>

$config.CreateLogger()

[Serilog.Log]::Logger = [Serilog.LoggerConfigurationElasticsearchExtensions]::Elasticsearch($ConfigSink, "http://192.168.1.125:9200", "custom-index-{0:yyyy.MM}", "asdd"),
                        ([Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel]::Verbose), "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}", $null, 10000000, 15).CreateLogger()

[Serilog.Log]::Information("Logging starte");
```

Comment: If you expect us to help you need to explain what doesn't work.

Comment: basically i wanted help with getting the *non-working* code i posted to work.The code snippet was just to show i was trying some different things, and did have any luck getting data into ES.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficent problem description. What do you expect the code to do, and what does it actually do? If you're getting errors: what do they say?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested in logging into ElasticSearch using PowerShell - You can use [PoShLog.Sinks.Elasticsearch](https://github.com/mamidenn/PoShLog.Sinks.Elasticsearch) module which is based on Serilog and it's ElasticSearch sink extension. Don't forget to install also main [PoShLog](https://github.com/PoShLog/PoShLog) module.

Example of using these modules:

```
Import-Module PoShLog
Import-Module PoShLog.Sinks.Elasticsearch

New-Logger |
    Add-SinkElasticsearch `
        -Uri 'http://elasticsearch:9200' `
        -AutoRegisterTemplate `
        -AutoRegisterTemplateVersion ESv7 `
        -IndexFormat 'logstash' |
    Add-SinkConsole |
    Start-Logger

Write-InformationLog "Hello {entity}!" -PropertyValues "World"

Close-Logger
```